# save json in HTML5 Web SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, html, web

I am new in HTML5 Web SQL Database and I want save a JSON string.

```
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO TA (id, name) VALUES (89,\"{   \"items\":[     {     \"order\": 1,     \"item_id\": 123123,     \"quantity\": 10,     \"price\": 1526896,     \"total\": 15268960   },   {     \"order\": 2,     \"item_id\": 113124,     \"quantity\": 10,     \"price\": 1526896,     \"total\": 15268960   },   {     \"order\": 3,     \"item_id\": 163125,     \"quantity\": 10,     \"price\": 1626896,     \"total\": 16268960   },   {     \"order\": 4,     \"item_id\": 1723165,     \"quantity\": 10,     \"price\": 1726896,     \"total\": 17268960   },   {     \"order\": 5,     \"item_id\": 183190,     \"quantity\": 10,     \"price\": 1826896,     \"total\": 18268960   } ],  \"other\":[           {         \"order\": 1,         \"item\": 123123,         \"price\": 10              },      {         \"order\": 2,         \"item\": 123123,         \"price\": 10              }      ,{         \"order\": 3,         \"item\": 123123,         \"price\": 10      }      ] }\")";
```

But it not accept quotation marks in value.

I test this sample

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO TA (id, name) VALUES (90,\"a\")");
```

Also

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO TA (id, name) VALUES (90,\"\"a\"\")");
```

And get same result.

Comment: What the error message?

Comment: Don't put the JSON string directly in the query. Use placeholders and parameters instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23434271/1233508

Comment: @Karl Richter HTML5 Web SQL Database never print log or error

Comment: @DCoder sloved thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers and specially @DCoder

> Don't put the JSON string directly in the query. Use placeholders and parameters instead: [stackoverflow.com/a/23434271/1233508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424431/websql-passing-values-in-as-parameter/23434271#23434271)

```
var str  = '{   "items":[     {     "order": 1,     "item_id": 123123,     "quantity": 10,     "price": 1526896,     "total": 15268960   },   {     "order": 2,     "item_id": 113124,     "quantity": 10,     "price": 1526896,     "total": 15268960   },   {     "order": 3,     "item_id": 163125,     "quantity": 10,     "price": 1626896,     "total": 16268960   },   {     "order": 4,     "item_id": 1723165,     "quantity": 10,     "price": 1726896,     "total": 17268960   },   {     "order": 5,     "item_id": 183190,     "quantity": 10,     "price": 1826896,     "total": 18268960   } ],  "other":[           {         "order": 1,         "item": 123123,         "price": 10              },      {         "order": 2,         "item": 123123,         "price": 10              }      ,{         "order": 3,         "item": 123123,         "price": 10      }      ] }';

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TA (id, name) VALUES (?,?)',[94,str]);
```